# How to use inline R code in a bookdown theorem or example environment

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown, theorem

I use bookdown to generate documents in both html and PDF. How could I use results from inline R code in theorem and example environments?

Here is what I tried:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: false
html_document:
    toc: false
---

```{r}
a <- 2
b <- 3
```

If $a = `r a`$ and $b = `r b`$, then $a + b = `r a + b`$.

```{theorem}
If $a = `r a`$ and $b = `r b`$, then $a + b = `r a + b`$.
```

```{example}
If $a = `r a`$ and $b = `r b`$, then $a + b = `r a + b`$.
```
````

and I get
[image: Result]

Comment: That is not possible with bookdown (at least for now).

Comment: @YihuiXie Is there any hope to have it work with something like
`r paste0("'''{example}\n")`
`r paste0("If $a = ", a, "$ and $b = ", b, ", then $a + b = ", a + b, "$.\n")`
`r paste0("'''")`
I can't find how to make it work with the ```.

Comment: Unfortunately, no...

Answer (score 2):

You could go with explicit Latex tags:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: false
html_document:
    toc: false
---

```{r}
a <- 2
b <- 3
```

\begin{theorem}

If $a = `r a`$ and $b = `r b`$, then $a + b = `r a + b`$.

\end{theorem}

\begin{example}

If $a = `r a`$ and $b = `r b`$, then $a + b = `r a + b`$.

\end{example}
````

[image]

Comment: Explicit LaTeX tags work fine for the PDF output but the html output doesn't contain the theorem nor the example (just the initial two lines of R code). Am I missing something?

Comment: No, this method will only work for Latex. I forgot to consider whether this would work for html.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this type of problems, I insert a blank environment (for numbering and reference only) and then write the content (you may want to end with a special character or `---`).

````
```{example, myexample}
```
If $a = `r a`$ and $b = `r b`$, then $a + b = `r a + b`$.

---

See for instance \@ref(exm:myexample)
````