# Bookdown (proof) custom environment: how to nest code chunks or inline R inside custom (e.g. proof) environments and get proper parsing?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, bookdown

I guess my question is a potential if not probable duplicate of [How to use inline R code in a bookdown theorem or example environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430980/how-to-use-inline-r-code-in-a-bookdown-theorem-or-example-environment). It's been nearly 3 years since this question was asked, so a refresh might be welcome in any case, all the more given @YiHui's comment: "*That is not possible with bookdown (at least for now)*"?

*Background*: I am trying to use @YiHui bookdown package to produce a book with lecture slides (see [creating accompanying slides for bookdown project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429949/creating-accompanying-slides-for-bookdown-project)). A key feature for this purpose is to be able to use conditional formatting, such as `eval = (out_type=="beamer")`. The issue I am facing is therefore to be able to add code chunks or inline R code inside bookdown custom environments (see https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems and https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/custom-blocks.html). I would love to get the following to compile properly. Is there a solution? Would a hook work (see https://yihui.org/knitr/hooks/)? There is a hack that works for forcing `pandoc` to parse inside a `latex` environment, but i do no think it applies here. Would a `lua filter` work (I have no idea how to use this)?

En passant, I am also surprised to see `$\digamma$` showing up properly in the `html` output, but not in the `pdf` output, though it is parsed correctly in the `tex` file. The `amssymb` package is loaded and it's supposedly defined in there - what am I missing?

Much appreciated any help on this.  Here is a MWE - I just edited chapter 4 from the default bookdown project. You can simply replace the contents of the file `03-method.Rmd` with the following:

````
# Methods

We describe our methods in this chapter.

So here is a theorem to prove 1+1 = `r 1+1`.

```{theorem, echo=TRUE}  
we want to show that in R, 1+1 = 2.  
We also wonder why `$\digamma$` ($\digamma$) not showing.  
Shows in the html output only, not pdf.  
But when I recompile the tex file produced by bookdown - shows up just fine!!  
Indeed, is defined correctly from `\usepackage{amssymb}`.  
```

```{proof, echo=TRUE}  
- If I am not mistaken, I cannot get an Rmarkdown style list to work either in the proof environment.
- Well, this is where i would like to be able to use inline code.  
- we use r to compute 1+1: `r 1+1`.  
- Does not work.  
- Just shows verbatim inline code.  
```
````

Comment: Would using a child document work?

Comment: i was also hoping something like `::: {.proof}` etc. `:::`  would work, but it does not - it fails to provide the proof environment, though it allows for inline expressions, etc - everything below parses properly.

Answer (score 2):

With the current development version of **bookdown**:

```
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```

you can write theorems in Pandoc's fenced Divs, e.g.,

```
# Methods

We describe our methods in this chapter.

So here is a theorem to prove 1+1 = `r 1+1`.

::: {.theorem}  
we want to show that in R, 1+1 = 2.  
We also wonder why `$\digamma$` ($\digamma$) not showing.  
Shows in the html output only, not pdf.  
But when I recompile the tex file produced by bookdown - shows up just fine!!  
Indeed, is defined correctly from `\usepackage{amssymb}`.  
:::

::: {.proof}  
- If I am not mistaken, I cannot get an Rmarkdown style list to work either in the proof environment.
- Well, this is where i would like to be able to use inline code.  
- we use r to compute 1+1: `r 1+1`.  
- Does not work.  
- Just shows verbatim inline code.  
:::
```

However, please note that this new syntax is not supported for beamer output yet.

Comment: is it possible to have labels and names with this syntax? `{.theorem, name="Important Theorem"}` doesn't seem to work